# Можно ли так делать в React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Например я хочу изменить объект стилей когда изменяется состояние colorMode таким образом :

styles.block.backgroundColor = colorMode

В react native чето не работает...
Какие варианты осуществления ещё есть подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Покажите, что у вас не получается кодом. Как пробовали. Изменить стили по состоянию компонента вполен себе возможно

Comment: Вопрос в том , что можно ли так просто взять и непосредственно обратиться к объекту и все применится

Comment: Не известно, пока вы не покажите, что за объект, что вы делаете, что не получается...